# How I can use my jquery plugin in Next.js?

Tags: import, hyperlink, jquery-plugins, reload, next.js

i'm developing web app using Next.js and I'd like to use jQuery in Next.js.
But I can't import jquery plugin.
please check my code and Help me.

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const page = renderPage(App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />));
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();
    return { ...page, styleTags };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>{this.props.styleTags}
          <link
            href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0/katex.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
         <script src="../static/js/jquery.main.js" async/>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <div id="modal" />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One typical issue you will get into if you do jQuery is, After importing the jQuery plugins they will register for onClick events, and by that time you can't guarantee that the actual DOM Element is ready, elements may get created later and may get refreshed.

One way of solving the issues is call the jQuery code which does the initialization in `componentDidMount()` and also in `componentDidUpdate()` so that you can make sure the DOM elements are present before the jQuery plugin register them.

Comment: hi,thanks for your help,would you please explain more detail with example code?