# Jquery script not working properly in nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, async.js

I am using an external CSS/Jquery UI kit in my app. I have added the scripts in _document.js

```
render() {
return (
  <Html>
    <Head />
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
      <script src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bulkit/extensions/bulma-steps.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bulkit/functions.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bulkit/main.js"></script>
    </body>
  </Html>
)}
```

In one my components, the CSS classes are not getting initialized properly.

```
 render () { auth.user && <RegistrationForm /> }
```

Here the component **RegistrationForm** uses the external CSS library and **auth.user** is set in an async manner (it checks for authentication in google firebase  and renders component accordingly)
If I remove **auth.user** , then the classes are getting initialized correctly and I can get the desired effect.

The init function in the jquery script is added here -
**$(document).ready(function($){ init_css_class }**

I tried changing that to **$(window).on('load', function (){})**.  Its still not working. I am not clear what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can use my jquery plugin in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012570/how-i-can-use-my-jquery-plugin-in-next-js)

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply. I tried loading the script using "useEffect" in that component.   useEffect(() => require('xxxx'), [])  I still see the same issue. Jquery is not properly registering the DOM elements for initialization. Is this something to do with nextjs server side rendering